# Consider two relations $R$ and $S$ on a set $A$ with $R$ being antisymmetric. Prove $R \cap S$ is antisymmetric.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations

Consider two relations $R$ and $S$ on a set $A$ with $R$ being antisymmetric. Prove $R \cap S$ is antisymmetric.

**Theorem** The subset of an antisymmetric relation is also antisymmetric.

The intersection $R \cap S$ of $R$ and $S$ is a subset of $R$:

$R \cap S \subseteq R$

Now, according to the theorem, since the subset of an antisymmetric relation is antisymmetric it follows that the intersection $R \cap S$ is also antisymmetric. This concludes the proof.

I now prove the theorem by contradiction. Let $T \subseteq R$ and $T$ is not antisymmetric. Then there exists elements of $T$ which violate antisymmetry, namely that there are elements $(x, y) \in T$ and $(y, x) \in T$ such that $x \neq y$. However, since $T$ is a subset of $R$ these elements would also be in $R$ which would mean that $R$ is not antisymmetric. But $R$ is antisymmetric, a contradiction. Therefore $T$ must be antisymmetric.

Is this proof correct? Or is there a better way to prove the claim?

Comment: Yes, the proof is good and I don't see how it can be *substantially* improved.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It seems that you do not need to phrase this as a contradiction. If $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are in $T$, then since $T\subset R$ we have $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are in $R$, so $x=y$. Thus, $T$ is anti-symmetric.

Comment: @walkar: I think that's all there is to say about this – if you write that as an answer, the question could be marked as answered. (See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35479.)

Comment: @joriki I've done so now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am making my comment an answer as well.

Your proof is technically accurate, but not *efficient* in the sense that you unnecessarily phrase it as a contradiction. A more direct method is as follows.

Suppose $R$ is an anti-symmetric relation and $T$ is a subset of $R$. Then, if $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are in $T$, we have $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are in $R$. Since $R$ is anti-symmetric, $x=y$. Thus, $T$ is also anti-symmetric.